# Checking if there's a duplicates in 2 columns, if yes then replace with new data or keep the old one? VBA

Tags: excel, vba

My excel file allows the user to upload new reports, each report can contain several invoices (each invoice = 1 row on Excel). If a user imports a new report but it seems to have already been uploaded based on 2 criteria: if the date **AND** the name appears already in past data, then give the option to *replace* or *keep* the old invoices.

Found this code here and adapted it to my sheet:
[How to Check for duplicates in 2 columns and copy the entire row into another sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564799/how-to-check-for-duplicates-in-2-columns-and-copy-the-entire-row-into-another-sh)

```
Sub Check()

Dim lw As Long, i As Long
  With targetSheet
     lw = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     For i = 2 To lw 
        If Application.CountIfs(Range("B" & i & ":B" & lw), Range("B" & i).Text, _
        Range("E" & i & ":E" & lw), Range("E" & i)) > 1 Then
            MsgBox ("A report was made on [DATE] with [NAME]. Do you want to replace the existing report or cancel?")
        End If
    Next i
  End With

End Sub
```

When I run this, it gives me error: Run-time error '424': Object Required

I also found this site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/prevent-duplicate-entries-in-a-range but not sure how to adapt it ..

Comment: I do not see where you declare or set `targetSheet`

Comment: Please ensure you're using Option Explicit as the first line in your module, preceeding any subroutines.  Additionally, check the qualifications for your ranges... one uses **.Range()**, the rest are just **Range()**

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this, @Jade:

```
Public Sub Check()

Dim lw As Long, i As Long

Worksheets("SheetName").Activate

lw = ActiveSheet.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lw 
        If Application.CountIfs(ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i & ":B" & lw), ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i).Value, ActiveSheet.Range("E" & i & ":E" & lw), ActiveSheet.Range("E" & i).Value) > 1 Then
            MsgBox "A report was made on [DATE] with [NAME]. Do you want to replace the existing report or cancel?", vbYesNo, "Title of MSGBOX"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: One should avoid activating sheets.  It slows down the code and 99% of the time is not needed.

Comment: Activation occurs only 1 time, at the begin of the code.
It was made to guarantee that the correct sheet would be used.

Comment: use a `With` block.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Check()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long

      With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<- Change if needed

         LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row '<- We assume that all columns have the same number of rows

         For i = 2 To LastRow '<- Start loop from second row
            'Let as assume that "Date" appears in column B. Check for duplicates
            If Application.CountIfs(.Range("B2" & ":B" & LastRow), .Range("B" & i).Value) > 1 Then '<- In order to find the duplicates in whole column avoid using i (used 1 or 2 depended on the row from where the range starts) in the range for search & add "." before range.
                'Let as assume that "Name" appears in column E. Check for duplicates
                If Application.CountIfs(.Range("E2" & ":E" & LastRow), .Range("E" & i).Value) > 1 Then
                    MsgBox ("A report was made on [DATE] with [NAME]. Do you want to replace the existing report or cancel?")
                End If
            End If

        Next i

      End With

End Sub
```